# How to package kivy application for Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, python, kivy

I have developed an application for Ubuntu using kivy and I want to distribute it but I am unable to package it.Please help this is my first application for Ubuntu.

There is no info in the official doc of kivy for packaging kivy application for linux (ubuntu). https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/packaging.html

I have tried this also but it didn't work for me. http://bitstream.io/packaging-and-distributing-a-kivy-application-on-linux.html

I am having dependencies of python3 and kivy.

I want to get the binaries that can be directly clicked and used with no installations. Can anyone help.

Comment: DId you try `Pyinstaller`?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is via [buildozer](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Install and then, in your application directory run:

```
buildozer debug deploy run
```

It will then deploy on any attached android devices.